# Poor performance of the msgpack serialization with gzip compression

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, gzip, msgpack

The following code snippet which serializes data to byte array is very slow on high load (3k req/h). Normally it takes several dozen seconds to finish, but sometimes it is more than 30 minutes (avg data size is about 1.5 MB). How to determine where the problem is?

```
                        var packer = new MsgPackDataWrapper<ResponseData>();
                        packer.RegisterOverridingSerializer(new NullableDecimalSerializer(packer.Context));
                        packer.RegisterOverridingSerializer(new NullableDateTimeSerializer(packer.Context));
                        response.Data = packer.SerializeCompressed(syncData);
```

compression:

```
    public byte[] SerializeCompressed(T source)
    {
        var data = this.Serialize(source);

        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                zipStream.Close();
                return compressedStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

msgpack serialization:

```
    public byte[] Serialize(T source)
    {
        var serializer = context.GetSerializer<T>(source);
        
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Pack(ms, source);
            
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```